# Hibernate 6.1.x / Spring Boot : avoid global temporary table creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate creates temporary tables for bulk operations.

We're using Oracle (*v19.0.0.0.0*) and our user won't have the privilege to create temporary table.

I've tried a lot of different configurations, but `HTE_` tables are still created on startup :

```
09:07:43.658 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      ] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
09:07:44.285 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       ] HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6dc5e857
09:07:44.286 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      ] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
09:07:44.596 INFO  [SQL dialect                             ] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
Hibernate: create global temporary table HTE_xxxxx(...) on commit delete rows
Hibernate: create global temporary table HTE_yyyyy(...) on commit delete rows
09:07:45.551 INFO  [j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

These configurations don't work :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.mutation_strategy=org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.temptable.LocalTemporaryTableMutationStrategy

OR 

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.mutation_strategy=org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.inline.InlineMutationStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.insert_strategy=org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.temptable.LocalTemporaryTableInsertStrategy
```

I'm using **Hibernate 6.1.7.Final** and **Spring Boot 3.0.6**.

I did not find other ways in the documentation : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Comment: I suspect you need to use the `LocalTemporaryTableMutationStrategy` which implements the correct interface instead of the `LocalTemporaryTableStrategy` which looks like a helper class for the former mentioned class.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working :  `Cannot instantiate the class [org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.temptable.LocalTemporaryTableMutationStrategy] because it does not have a constructor that accepts a dialect or an empty constructor`. 
App starts if I use `org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.inline.InlineMutationStrategy`  but global temporary table are still created...

Comment: Try `local_temporary` as the full name (that seems to be the shortcut for it). If it doesn't implement the interface/appropriate strategy it will do the default (which is global tables, judging from the source code).

Comment: Next to `mutation_strategy` you probably also want to set the `insert_strategy` to the same. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.mutation_strategy= local_temporary` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.insert_strategy= local_temporary`

Comment: With the `mutation_strategy` and `insert_strategy`set, I still have the `Cannot instantiate the class [org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.temptable.LocalTemporaryTableMutationStrategy] because it does not have a constructor that accepts a dialect or an empty constructor` exception.

Comment: You are setting it with `local_temporary`? Or still the full classname?

Comment: I tried both, but the last try was with the short name `local_temporary` as in your comment.

Comment: Feels like this is broken by design or something. Only the `InlineMutationStrategy` has a constructor that satisfies the constructor with a `Dialect`. All others have other constructors, not satisfying the constraint. I would register a ticket with Hibernate for t his.

Comment: You're right, and I can't use this strategy for the `insert_strategy` because it does not exist (strategies implementing `SqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` are only cte/global/local/persistent-table` strategies `. Thanks for your time and help, I will keep digging...

Comment: And yes you can use the `local_temporary` strategy as that maps to the local one. Check the code. Your initial class `LocalTemporaryTableStrategy` serves as a base class to both of those and the static name is used for the different strategies. (I did check on 6.2.2 I just noticed, not 6.1)

Comment: I tried to ignore the fact that I can't create global temporary tables and I ran my app without any properties configuring this aspect. The app starts and I can do everything, even if the `HTE_` tables are not present... I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Hibernate [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15550) that has been solved in `6.2.0` :

> In addition to the
> hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy.global_temporary.drop_tables and
> hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy.persistent.drop_tables settings, add a
> create_tables variant which allows to control whether to create
> tables. Keep it true by default to retain backwards compatibility.

Spring Boot 3.1 upgrades to Hibernate 6.2, so upgrading SB to `3.1.x` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue - and the solution is simple and hidden inside hibernate doc migration:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html

Note that the configuration property hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy was changed to hibernate.query.mutation_strategy which will now refer to classes or objects implementing

So the answer is for example:

```
hibernate.query.mutation_strategy=org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.inline.InlineMutationStrategy
hibernate.query.mutation_strategy.global_temporary.create_tables=false
hibernate.query.mutation_strategy.global_temporary.drop_tables=false
```